# Query author's posts & posts that have author's id as meta value

Tags: hooks, meta-query

I am trying to get posts with an author's ID as a meta value in the `author.php` template using additional request parameter.

For example I want posts with john's ID as a meta value using a request like this

```
http://localhost:8888/twitgreen/author/john/?eco=somemetakey
```

So far I can make it using a `new WP_query` in author.php like this

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

if($_GET['eco']=='somemetakey'){
    $lot = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'somemetakey',
                'value' => $current_view->ID
            )
        ),
        'post_type'=>'lot',
        'paged'=>$paged ,
    );
}

$wp_query = new WP_Query($lot);

//and some loop here

<nav id="nav-below">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'clonecell' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'clonecell' ) ); ?></div>
</nav><!-- #nav-below -->
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work on the next pages. The URL, `http://localhost:8888/twitgreen/author/verifikator/page/2/?eco=somemetakey` points to the 404 page.

**The Question**

- How can I query posts with an author's ID as a meta value in the author.php?
- How can I query posts with an authors's ID as a meta value or post from that author in author.php?
- How can I do this requests using WordPress hooks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative approach to answer the problem**

So far I havent found any method to do that. One would be better of creating a custom page for any custom query than modifying the author.php.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a new WP_Query, use the `pre_get_posts` filter

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_query');
function custom_query($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author() && $_GET['eco']=='somemetakey') {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'somemetakey',
                'value' => $query->get('author')
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it still need to unset the author parameter. I'll let you know if I find it in Google